# Services and flask_sqlalchemy inside a flask application

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building a large, complex Flask application. It has lots of route functions (which need to do database calls) and lots of services (which also need to do database calls).

I'm using flask_sqlalchemy to do the database calls in the route functions as normal with model syntax (User.query).

I would also like to make database calls in the services. However, I can't do this without setting an app context:

```
with app.app_context():
    User.query
```

which requires importing the app, which leads to circular imports (because the app imports the routes, which import the services, which have to import the app).

QUESTION 1: Do you know a way to get round this circular import problem?

Another approach could be to use flask_sqlalchemy in the routes and sqlalchemy in the services. This means nothing needs to be shared except for the database url and.... the models.

QUESTION 2: Do you know a way to use the same model files with both flask_sqlalchemy and normal sqlalchemy?

I've tried this: https://dev.to/nestedsoftware/flask-and-sqlalchemy-without-the-flask-sqlalchemy-extension-3cf8

...however it breaks my relationships.

I am following the flask app pattern shown here: https://github.com/sloria/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/README.rst (application factory)

Thanks,
Louise

Comment: can you show `app`, `sqlalchemy` initialization and example of service ?

Comment: They're exactly as in the Flask app pattern shown in the link.
A service is an instance of a custom class which needs a reference to the app to be passed in the constructor (to use appcontext). Exactly like the database or security extensions.